# Does money sync between Xbox 360 and Xbox One?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have already transferred my gta account to the Xbox one but my friends say if I go back to the 360 and earn money on it, it will link with my Xbox one account and give me the money I got on Xbox 360 is that true?

Comment: I thought character transfer was a one time deal.  I don't think you can go back on your 360.

Comment: Yes I gathered that as much... what I was trying to say is that if I earn $500 dollars on my Xbox 360 gta it would also give me $500 dollars on my Xbox one? You know what I mean?

Comment: I don't think so I can look into it later

Comment: No it doesn't. You get a one time transfer to copy your 360 account into xb1 account. You can't go from xb1 back to 360 or go from 360 to xb1 again. If you could, everyone would play on 360 version for free $

Comment: Yes that is true, thanks for looking into it for me bud

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the transfer is a one-time deal and there's no link of any sort between the two consoles. Furthermore, any money or statistics earned on the Xbox One will not be present on the 360.